# Why does SHParseDisplayName give an access violation if I've imported it myself?

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-shell

I get an access violation when trying to get a pidl form a path in Delphi, and the returned pidl is nil. This is my code:

```
type
  // TParseDisplayName = function(pszPath: PChar; pbc: pointer; var pidl: PItemIDList; sfgaoIn: LongWord; var psfgaoOut: LongWord): LongInt;
  TParseDisplayName = function(pszPath: PWideChar; pbc: IBindCtx; var pidl: PItemIDList; sfgaoIn: ULong; var psfgaoOut: ULong): HResult;

var
  SHParseDisplayName: TParseDisplayName;
  SHELL32DLLHandle : THandle;

procedure test();
var
  ws : WideString;
  tmpLongWord: ULong;
  lpItemID: PItemIDList;
begin
  //ws := 'Mes documents';

  CoInitialize(nil);

  // path to test
  ws := 'C:\inetsdk\Nouveau Document WordPad.doc';

  if (SHParseDisplayName(PWideChar(ws), nil, lpItemID, 0, tmpLongWord) = S_OK) then
    if not assigned(lpItemID) then      
      s := SysErrorMessage(getLastError);

  CoUnInitialize();
end;

initialization
  SHELL32DLLHandle  := LoadLibraryW('shell32.dll');

  @SHParseDisplayName := GetProcAddress(SHELL32DLLHandle, 'SHParseDisplayName');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The declaration of `TParseDisplayName` omits the calling convention. You need to include `stdcall`.

```
TParseDisplayName = function(pszPath: PWideChar; pbc: IBindCtx; 
  var pidl: PItemIDList; sfgaoIn: ULong; var psfgaoOut: ULong): HResult; stdcall;
```

When you don't specify a calling convention the default calling convention is used. The default calling convention is `register`. This has different semantics for parameter passing and clean up which leads to the type of runtime error you have experienced. Practically all Windows API functions used `stdcall`.

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I really appreciate your quick help David !

Comment: @Ken Actually blitzers do get the rep back. But no blitz attack from current stalker who knows how things work here.

Comment: @David: That's why downvoting costs rep.  And unless a whole bunch of people downvote, it's meaningless. I find that a lot of really good answers get both + and - votes.